# Native sendmail commands to operate the mail queue?

Tags: centos, sendmail, mail-command

I'm on a CentOS 7 server that runs `sendmail` and unfortunately I'm not allowed to install new packages. Postfix tools are not installed; AFAIK the only tool available is `mailq`, that permits only to see the mailqueue.

Is there a way to operate easily on the mailqueue, apart from grepping or deleting the files `/var/spool/mqueue/*` by hand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To deal with queues in sendmail you have the qtool.pl utility in the contrib sendmail source code directory. Nowadays in some distributions, qtool.pl is installed together with sendmail.

[qtool - manipulate sendmail queues](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man8/qtool.8.html)

> EXAMPLES
>
> ```
>    qtool.pl q2 q1
>           Moves all of the queue files in queue q1 to queue q2.
>
>    qtool.pl q2 q1/d6CLQh100847
>           Moves the message with id d6CLQh100847 in queue q1 to queue q2.
>
>    qtool.pl q2 q1/qfd6CLQh100847
>           Moves the message with id d6CLQh100847 in queue q1 to queue q2.
>
>    qtool.pl -e '$msg{num_delivery_attempts} == 3' /q2 /q1
>           Moves  all  of  the  queue  files  that have had three attempted
>           deliveries from queue q1 to queue q2.
> ```

Please see also:

[Sendmail: Clear / Delete / Flush Mail Queue](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-clear-sendmail-queue/)